# Kendo UI Gantt - Jquery - Error showing URL too long

Tags: internet-explorer, kendo-ui, rendering, gantt-chart

I am having issue with Kendo UI for Jquery - Gantt in two cases:
Gantt when saved with 15-20 tasks an error is thrown as URL too long.

When I try to save Gantt data with items more than 15 or so, it throws request header URL too long.
As the Kendo UI Gantt is using GET method and the total data (JSON data) is posted thru header and is throwing request header URL too long.

Do we have an option of submitting data from Gantt using POST method instead GET method.  If yes, please provide a sample code that can be tested using Kendo UI Jquery - Gantt.  If no, let us know how the issue can be resolved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please move the IE 11 issue to a separate question.

Comment: Can you post a dojo similar to your Gannt? The example at https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/gantt/index saves added items one by one, so I don't know how to reproduce the error.

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I have tested the [Kendo UI Gantt sample](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/gantt/index) on IE browser, they all works well. So, perhaps there is something wrong with your code, it is better to share your code.

Comment: We need to know how you've implemented the save functionality. Are you using a Kendo UI Gantt internal function like 'transport.update'? Have you added an external "Save" button? You need to provide more data and preferably a code snippet or even a demo.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. I will be providing the sample workable code to have better understanding on the issue.  But it may take a bit time as i am working on other high priority tasks of the project.

Comment: @GaloisGirl

As this is the first time i have logged a query, i am not sure how this chain get closed.

Can you please make it complete.  Please see my previous comment added which explains how it got resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identified the cause of the issue, when i was trying to fix some other issue.

I identified that the Ajax way of posting data was not explored earlier and we were not able to utilize the POST method.

As Gantt by default uses GET method and the data is always passed thru the URL in GET method and hence was failing when the data exceeds the URL transport limit.

By changing the method to POST using ajax approach, the issue got resolved.

Thank you all for the support given to try resolving the issue.